# An error from an HTTP call is not caught when I subscribe to the result, but is caught in my HTTP interceptor

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I am on Angular 10 (I was on 8 before with the same issue). In the following method, I subscribe to an HTTP request in my component:

```
    this.httpData.updateRadioAnswers(questions)
    .subscribe(
      result => this.requestResult = <any>result,
      error => {
        this.requestError = <any>error;
        console.log('error! '+this.requestError);
      },
      () => {
          console.log(this.requestResult);
      });
```

And I also have this HTTP interceptor:

```
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (this.oauth.token && !req.headers.has('Authorization')) {
            req = req.clone(this.getHttpHeaders(null));
            return next.handle(req).pipe(
                tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => { }, err => {
                    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                })
            );
        } else {
            return next.handle(req);
        }
    }
```

When my HTTP request is not successful, I would like to handle the error in my component (first block), but the code inside "error" never gets executed. However, the code for "err" in the interceptor will get executed when an error occurs. How can I properly execute some block of code in my component when the HTTP request throws an error? I don't want to handle this in the interceptor, since I want to customize error messages for different requests, rather than them be all the same from the interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (this.oauth.token && !req.headers.has('Authorization')) {
        req = req.clone(this.getHttpHeaders(null));
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError(error => throwError(error))
        )
    } else {
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still does not execute the code in the error portion of my subscription in the component